# Make Middle Slide as Active in Light Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I cant figure out how I can make the middle slider as active instead of the first slide in light slider. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you give us more information? What middle slider, what exactly is your problem, can you give us a minimal working example with the problem from your current code?

Comment: I have this slider called lightslider from github. Then I have 3 slides. The first slide is always active upon checking. All I want is that the middle slide will become the active slide for me to design it bigger that the other slides. Here's the expected outcome: https://nimb.ws/5GQeSs